# How to extract nested elements in JSON response using JSON extractor

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

I need to extract an element based on a condition inside a nested JSON response.

```
{
   "cabin":"eco",
   "seatNumber":"15A",
   "travelers":[
      {
         "id":"7789",
         "seatCharacteristicsCodes":[
            "CH",
            "W"
         ],
         "seatAvailabilityStatus":"available",
         "prices":[
            {
               "base":40,
               "total":40,
               "currencyCode":"AED",
               "totalTaxes":0
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "coordinates":{
      "x":1,
      "y":0
   }
}
```

I need to check the "seatAvailabilityStatus" as "available" or not (which is inside "travelers"), if it is available, I need to get the "seatNumber" and proceed with the flow.

I have seen some example and tried like the below, but I am able to capture only the values which are associated to "travelers" like "id" or "prices":

```
$.travelers[?(@.seatAvailabilityStatus=="available")].id
```

But in my case, if the seatAvailabilityStatus is available I need to get the "seatNumber". Can anyone help?

[Screen shot of the JSON I included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtCr6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this way:

```
$..[?(@.travelers[?(@.seatAvailabilityStatus =='available')] empty false)].seatNumber
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to get 1 level up because JsonPath [doesn't know anything about parents of the matched attribute](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287)

Suggested query:

```
$..[?(@.travelers[?(@.seatAvailabilityStatus =='available')])].seatNumber
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)

Comment: with this query even if the `seatAvailabilityStatus` in unavailable it will still output the same result. as mentioned by @Venkatesan you also need to compare the inner most filtered object with empty false